# Не идет пинг Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ping, lxc

Я создал lxc контейнер с Ubuntu на борту. Перед этим у меня был контейнер на Debian. Все настройки сети были сделаны и он работал. Но когда я ввел те же настройки для нового контейнера (с Ubuntu) - сеть не работает, команда

```
ping ya.ru
```

выдает

```
ping: unknown host ya.ru
```

Команда apt-update тоже не обновляет, говорит что недоступно. Помогите хотя б советом, куда смотреть. Спасибо

Comment: А что выдает `ping 8.8.8.8` ?

Comment: И заодно `dig ya.ru`

Comment: А в контейнере можно выполнить cat /etc/resolv.conf ?

Comment: `ping 8.8.8.8` идет, `dig ya.ru` - `bash: dig: command not found`, `cat /etc/resolv.conf` выполняется, но файл пустой

Answer (score 1):

проблема была в том, что файл **/etc/resolv.conf** был пустой. перенес туда настройки с предыдущего контейнера - все заработало